# Solr - Sort documents based on chidren

Tags: solr

I have a schema with nested documents that looks like:

```
{
    "id":"227686",
    "ProductID":"227686",
    "type":"product",
    "SKU":"DAFA2A1F047E438B8462667F987D80A5",
    "Name":"product name",
    "ShortDescription":"s description",
    "UOM":"Unit",
    "UomSize":"48",
    "CategoryID":59,
    "CategoryName":"Produce",
    "ManufacturerID":322,
    "ManufacturerName":"-------",
    "Active":"true",
    "_version_":1509403723402575872,
    "_childDocuments_":[
    {
      "id":"227686_83",
      "type":"buyer",
      "BuyerID":83,
      "DisplayOrder":0,
      "ProductID":"227686"},
    {
      "id":"227686_86",
      "type":"buyer",
      "BuyerID":86,
      "DisplayOrder":10,
      "ProductID":"227686"},
    {
      "id":"227686_83_84",
      "type":"seller",
      "BuyerID":83,
      "SellerID":84,
      "SellerName":"-----",
      "ProductID":"227686"},
    {
      "id":"227686_83_89",
      "type":"seller",
      "BuyerID":83,
      "SellerID":89,
      "SellerName":"-----",
      "ProductID":"227686"},
    ]},
```

Is there a way to query so I can get parent documents sorted by child document's DisplayOrder field?

I want to query for a product name and get results for a specific buyer and I do:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dine/select?q=Name:"product name"&fq={!parent%20which=type:product v="type:buyer AND BuyerID=83"}&wt=json&indent=true&fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=type:product%20childFilter=%22((type:buyer%20AND%20BuyerSiteID:83)%20OR%20(type:seller%20AND%20BuyerSiteID:83))%22%20%20limit=1000]&rows=1000
```

But the results are not sorted by child document's DisplayOrder field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a function sort see: https://blog.griddynamics.com/how-to-sort-parent-documents-by-child-attributes-in-solr

```
&sort={!parent which=doc_type:parent score=max v=’+doc_type:child +{!func}DisplayOrder’} asc
```

This means that you will need to add a field to identify the parent and child.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sort parameter to achieve this.

> sort: The sort parameter arranges search results in either ascending (asc) or descending (desc) order. The parameter can be used with either numerical or alphabetical content.

You need to either index your DisplayOrder field or define it as DocValue in the schema and it should not be a multivalue field.

If you do not define DisplayOrder field as DocValues then it should not be tokenzied by any analyzer or it should uses KeywordTokenizer, which essentially produces single term.

You can find the more information here. [Common Query Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters)

Comment: The problem is that DisplayOrder comes from a child document and I want the parents sorted.